# Entityqueue + inline entity creation?

Tags: 7, entities

### Background / use case

The [entityqueue](https://drupal.org/project/entityqueue) module is a great way to bridge content with configuration:

- The entity queue is created in config, and created automatically on deployment. It can then be included into a panels page or another type of configured element.
- The entities can be created, placed and controlled by editors, without polluting the exported configuration (stored in features for D7) of the queue.
- The ordering of items is controlled by the editor.
- The weights are stored outside the actual entities, which means that sorting does not fire all the entity update hooks.

The usual way would be to let editors add existing nodes to the queue.

Now we want a bit more than that: Every entry should have a custom title + link destination, in addition to the reference to a node.

### Current solution idea

The first idea would be an entity queue with a list of "mini entities" (e.g. using [eck](https://drupal.org/project/eck) or [nestedbox](https://drupal.org/project/nestedbox)), each with a title field, link field, and an entityreference field to reference the node.

Editors would have to create those mini entities, and then add them to the queue.

### Question

Is there an easy way to combine the two steps of creating the mini entity, and adding it to the queue?

Is it possible for the queue to "own" these mini entities, like a node "owns" its paragraphs items? We don't want to end up with a pool of homeless mini entities.

---

### Alternatives I considered

#### Solutions which require a "host entity"

Another solution could be a [paragraphs](https://drupal.org/project/paragraphs) field.

Or something else with [inline entity form](https://drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form). A colleague built a solution with a fieldable panels pane referencing other fieldable panels panes via entityreference + inline entity form.

In all of these solutions we need a host entity, which would itself be content and not configuration, with the known flaws:

- The host entity is content and not configuration, and thus won't be automatically created on deployment.
- If the host entity is placed e.g. into a panel, it will pollute the exported configuration due to its auto-increment id or uuid.

#### Solution with taxonomy terms?

Taxonomy terms already give us a sorting UI out of the box. So we could create a vocabulary with some fields, and use the terms as "mini entities". Then the term weight would replace the entity queue.

One flaw in this solution is that every queue would require a new vocabulary (taxonomy bundle), because the sorting is global to the entire vocabulary.

#### Content export for host entity?

Perhaps the problem with the "host entity" would be solved by exporting the entity to config with its uuid?

Firstly I am not sure how well this works in general.

But either way, if the host entity is exported in config, then changing the referenced mini entities would pollute the configuration.

#### Host entity in a queue?

Another option would be to have

- a host entity with paragraphs or entityreference + inline entity form for the mini entities, as above
- a queue holding the host entity.
- create an empty host entity on deployment with hook_update_N().

This will properly isolate content from exported configuration.

However, now the editor needs to know the url of the correct host entity when editing.

Also, since the host entity is officially content, it could get messed up by editors.

Overall this adds one level of content architecture which I would rather avoid.

Comment: For anyone looking to accomplish this in D8, entity queue + inline entity form + eck seems to work if you're using the latest versions. I ran into a weird issue with an empty label on form display, but you can adjust that in hook_preprocess_inline_entity_form_entity_table().